# Intellij IDEA @OneToMany mappedBy attribute error resolving

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea

I have a little problem with 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "table_name") annotations in JPA.
So we have 2 tables (all details on screenshot)
I added a datasource, but i still have error "Cannot resolve attribute"

Can i resolve it some way?

```
@Id
@Column(name = "state_id")
public int getStateId() {
    return stateId;
}

public void setStateId(int stateId) {
    this.stateId = stateId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "systemname")
public String getSystemName() {
    return systemName;
}

public void setSystemName(String systemname) {
    this.systemName = systemname;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "note_states")
public Set<Note> getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(Set<Note> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}
```

[image: My problem]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mappedBy attribute value is not supposed to be a table name. It's supposed to be, in a bidirectional association, the name of the attribute in the other entity, that maps the association.

Example:

```
public class Country {
    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCountry");
    private Set<City> cities;
}

public class City {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColomn(name = "country_id")
    private Country parentCountry;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to Hibernate and you point out that " mappedBy attribute value supposed to be the name of the attribute in the other entity", I wanna know where this is defined? can you give me some offical links? I made the same mistake as the original question  because I've got some examples that the other entity has the same attribute as the table name of the entity which use mappedBy by coincidence. and for you example, the name attribute of JoinColomn, I guess it is something like THENAMEOFOTHERENTITY_ATTRIBUTE, but I don't know if it is correct.